# Problem with a variable with the same value in different functions (C ++)

Tags: c++

Do you know if there is any way to save the value of an assigned variable in one function to use it in another function?

In this case, I have a program that asks me to enter the name of the variable `nombre` in the function `registro();` to register a plant. For example, if I enter `Maguey de sol`, the program prints:

`¿Quieres continuar con el registro de Maguey de sol?`

So far everything works fine. The problem appears when I press any key to continue. The program should print:

`La planta es Maguey de sol`

But it only prints:

`La planta es`

I know that a solution is to include the code of the function `registro();` in `main();`, but it is not a viable option, because in my program I use more functions.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>     // Español
#include <string>       // Cadenas
#include <fstream>      // Ficheros

using namespace std;

bool registro();

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish"); // Español
    
    string nombre;
    
    registro();
    
    cout << "La planta es " << nombre << endl;

    return 0;
}

bool registro(){    
    string nombre;
    
    cout << "\n \t Ingresa el nombre de la planta" << endl;
    cout << "\t (Máximo 15 caracteres) \n \n" << endl;
    
    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);
    
    while (getline(cin, nombre)){
        if (nombre.size() <= 15){
            cout << "\n \t ¿Quieres continuar con el registro de " << nombre << "?\n" << endl;
            system("pause");
            break;  
        }else{
            cout << "\n \t ¡El nombre debe tener un máximo de 15 caracteres! \n" << endl;   
        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `return` the value from `registro`.

Comment: Alternatively you could write a plant class with `string nombre` as member variable and `registro()` and `sayName()` as member functions, which both can access the nombre variable. Other advantages are, you can create one object instance per plant. `registro()` could also be a constructor or be called by the constructor of the plant class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what you're trying to achieve, but to elaborate on Stephen Newell 's comment, here is a modified version of your code.

Although your `nombre` variable**s** have the same name, they are technically different variables, and therefore have different values, in each of their respective scope. Learn more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h> // Español
#include <string>   // Cadenas
#include <fstream>  // Ficheros

using namespace std;

string registro();

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish"); // Español

    string nombre;

    nombre = registro();

    cout << "La planta es " << nombre << endl;

    return 0;
}

string registro()
{
    string nombre;

    cout << "\n \t Ingresa el nombre de la planta" << endl;
    cout << "\t (Máximo 15 caracteres) \n \n"
         << endl;

    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);

    while (getline(cin, nombre))
    {
        if (nombre.size() <= 15)
        {
            cout << "\n \t ¿Quieres continuar con el registro de " << nombre << "?\n"
                 << endl;
            // system("pause");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n \t ¡El nombre debe tener un máximo de 15 caracteres! \n"
                 << endl;
        }
    }
    return nombre;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. And thanks for the additional information from Geeks for Geeks, that cleared up all my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the global variable or use my way as below. Return value for **registro** function.

```
/******************************************************************************

                              Online C++ Compiler.
               Code, Compile, Run and Debug C++ program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string registro();

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish"); // Español
    
    string nombre= registro();
    
    
    
    cout << "La planta es " << nombre << endl;

    return 0;
}

string registro(){   
    string nombre;
    cout << "\n \t Ingresa el nombre de la planta" << endl;
    cout << "\t (Máximo 15 caracteres) \n \n" << endl;
    
    cin.clear();
    fflush(stdin);
    
    while (getline(cin, nombre)){
        cout<<nombre<<endl;
        if (nombre.size() <= 15){
            cout << "\n \t Quieres continuar con el registro de " << nombre << "?\n" << endl;
            system("pause");
            break;  
        }else{
            cout << "\n \t El nombre debe tener un máximo de 15 caracteres! \n" << endl;   
        }
    }   
    return nombre;
}
```